# Rasdial error 756 only solved by rebooting

Tags: windows-xp, vpn, batch-file

I have a very frustrating issue with a VPN connection initiated with Rasdial.

I have computers (Windows XP Professional SP2) which serve as an unmanned field measuring devices. They automatically initiate a VPN connection with a server over a UMTS connection through the use of a batch file that I call from an application.

For the connection to be initiated I use the following batch file:

```
rasdial vpnserver /disconnect

rasdial VPNserver stationname password
```

This works fine as long as the UMTS connection is up and healthy. However if the UMTS drops for whatever reason and then comes back again, I can't get the VPN connection up again. When I run the above batch file I get the error:

> 756 "connection is already being dialled"

I can't manage to get the connection "cleared" .The only way to connect again is through rebooting the whole computer, which is not acceptable.

I have tried to expand the batch file as follows;

```
rasdial vpnserver /disconnect

route -f

ipconfig /release

ipconfig /renew

arp -d *

nbtstat -R

nbtstat -RR

ipconfig /flushdns

ipconfig /registerdns

rasdial VPNserver stationname password
```

to try and reset anything which has something to do with networking. Sadly this doesn't have any effect, I still get the same error.

There must be something that gets reset by rebooting the machine, but I can't manage to find out what this is and how to do this from the command line.

How I can solve this issue without rebooting the whole machine?

Comment: From a quick look up this problem has been common with XP and Vista... could you use a different VPN client? OpenVPN as a different VPN technology so you're not relying on the MS API?

Comment: (1) Try to trace the problem as [described here](http://blogs.technet.com/b/rrasblog/archive/2005/12/22/416421.aspx). (2) Disable all other network adapters. (3) Does the problem ever clear up after some time?

Comment: I have got this problem in windows 10. Still no answer?

Answer (score 0):

I've had a similar problem on Windows 7. Sometimes, after losing physical connection and redialling PPPoE automatically, rasautou.exe would start rapidly consuming gigabytes of RAM. After the rasautou process is killed, rasman service stops responding and can't be restarted by normal means.

In those cases it would be possible to restart the rasman service by finding and killing relevant svchost.exe process. rasdial and rasphone should work again after that.

To avoid interference with other services, rasman can be set to run in its own process: `sc config rasman type= own`

To avoid the problem entirely, I've also disabled automatic redialling in the connection properties. Instead, I've created an event-triggered Task Scheduler task to call rasdial. That also allows redialling on a wider range of errors, dialling up on startup and prevents redialling window from stealing focus.

Setting up such task has some caveats. Examples can be seen [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/771eeb9a-77e6-428f-8e23-3433d1421757/auto-redial-for-internet-connections-in-windows-8#f14f39f5-147c-41f9-8359-c4c3ea245978) and [there](https://serverfault.com/questions/892795/auto-reconnect-vpn-on-disconnection-due-to-any-reason-persistent-vpn). Involved XPath implementation has [limitations](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wes/consuming-events#xpath-10-limitations) and quirks, so be sure to test your custom event filters in the Event Viewer. [Remote Access Error Codes](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/rras/routing-and-remote-access-error-codes). You'll also want to change that task to "Queue a new instance if the task is already running".

I use 2 separate triggers. One which excludes code 631 (manual disconnect) and 651:

```
<QueryList>
  <Query Id="0" Path="Application">
    <Select Path="Application">*[System[Provider/@Name='RasClient'][EventID=20226 or EventID=20227]]</Select>
    <Suppress Path="Application">*[EventData[Data[4]=631 or Data[4]=651]]</Suppress>
  </Query>
</QueryList>
```

And another one for 651 with a 5-second delay:

```
<QueryList>
  <Query Id="0" Path="Application">
    <Select Path="Application">*[System[Provider/@Name='RasClient'][EventID=20227]][EventData/Data[4]=651]</Select>
  </Query>
</QueryList>
```

Sometimes instead of throwing error 651 rasman will start 2-minute timeout and throw 638. I couldn't find any way to adjust that timeout. But if you kill rasdial.exe during that time, you'll hang rasman.

Answer (score -1):

`rasdial /disconnect` disconnects all connections, regardless of name

Comment: Nope, not in this scenario, not when it "crashes".